# Avoiding BLANK ROW with 'Stretch with Overflow' in report

Tags: jasper-reports

In my jasper report, i have 9 columns. For the col2 and col9, set the properties as

```
isStretchWithOverflow="true" 
positionType="Float" 
stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" 
isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" 
isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" 
isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"
```

So the values in col2 and col9 are stretched when the data overflows in **EXCEL** export. But the issues is, when the col2 or col9 is stretched in columnwise when the data overflows, at the same time it was adding **BLANK ROW** for col1,col3....col8. 
Also i have added the property to avoid the blank row

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
```

**

> [Link to sample excel export file](http://wikisend.com/download/315614/test.xls)

**

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"` on all the other fields so that they change height when col2 and col9 stretch on overflow. This way all thew fields in a single row will have the same height.